# Hiding output from console

Tags: r, console, summary, suppress

My code contains a command which is essential for it to run, however it ends up showing the result of this command in the console, i have tried to use `suppressWarnings()`, `suppressMessages()`, `invisible()` and `sink()` but all of these still show the result.

Here is an example data set and where the problem originates from:

```
M<-c(1111,1222,1333,1444,1555,1666,1777,2223,6654,9867,1123,1456,2436,6875)
fstAdi <- ets(ts(rep(M,length = length(M)), deltat= 1/4, start = c(8,1)), model = "AAA", damped = FALSE, opt.crit = "mae", ic="aic", lower = c(0, 0, 0, 0), upper = c(0.999, 0.999, 0.999, 0.999), bounds = "admissible", restrict = FALSE)
mae11Ad<-summary(fstAdi)[,"MAE"]
```

The last line of the code above always shows the summary in the console, which when automating this for a report causing problems. Does anyone know of a command which can stop this happening?

Thankyou

I have found a way to hide it while automating the report, but if anyone knows how to hide it while just running the code to make the process quicker then that would be really helpful anyway :)

Comment: Which package does `ets` come from?

Comment: from tseries or forecast i believe, sorry i forgot about that part in the code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sink` does work, how exactly are you using it? Try for example

```
M<-c(1111,1222,1333,1444,1555,1666,1777,2223,6654,9867,1123,1456,2436,6875)
fstAdi <- ets(ts(rep(M,length = length(M)), deltat= 1/4, start = c(8,1)), model = "AAA", damped = FALSE, opt.crit = "mae", ic="aic", lower = c(0, 0, 0, 0), upper = c(0.999, 0.999, 0.999, 0.999), bounds = "admissible", restrict = FALSE)
sink(tempfile())
mae11Ad<-summary(fstAdi)[,"MAE"]
sink()
```

Comment: Thankyou that does work :) i will remember that for future use! :)

Answer (score 6):

The summary method for `ets` objects is a bit verbose:

```
> forecast:::summary.ets
function (object, ...) 
{
    print(object)
    cat("\nTraining set error measures:\n")
    print(accuracy(object))
}
<bytecode: 0x161d31c8>
<environment: namespace:forecast>
```

This is pretty bad style, summary methods should return an object with a class and the print method for that class should produce the output.

So you could just call the `accuracy` method on your object:

```
> accuracy(fstAdi)[,"MAE"]
[1] 1971.468
```

which has the advantage of not needing any diversion of output and is more readable.

Comment: Thankyou, i was using someone elses code so i hadnt looked into all the little details like that. Thankyou, I will apply your answer to the code now :)

Answer (score 2):

I know that probably looks like a bad-style approach, but this seems to work

```
sink( tempfile() )
mae11Ad<-summary(fstAdi)[,"MAE"]
```